# Is it possible to remove all .Net MVC components in a .Net Web Api application so that I can use AngularJS as the front end?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating an application with a .Net Web Api project wanting to use pure AngularJS as the client side.  Since Web Api is built on top of MVC, it creates MVC specific and default items that I feel is not needed.  These items include the HomeController, _ViewStart.cshtml, _layout.cshtml, etc.  I tried removing them but it comes up with errors.  Has anyone tried to remove the MVC stuff out of the web api project and used separate client side front-end?  Is it even possible to remove the MVC items without errors?

Comment: None of the elements you've cited have anything to do with the front-end programming.

Comment: I believe you actually want to keep all the MVC infrastructure, it has to do with user management, authentication, authorization, and it contains all the HTTP plumbing to support the ajax calls your angular application will make.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Okay so maybe it's more of the routing.  How can I remove the MVC items, specifically the routing (RouteConfig.cs) so I can use AngularJS's routing instead?

Comment: @Larbear remember any URL that points to a physical file will be served by MVC as is, so you can put all your html files in a separate folder. Angular routing should not conflict with MVC routing.

Comment: Why not just create a WebAPI only project? When you create a new web app uncheck the mvc box and leave webapi checked.

Comment: @AviadP. Thank you for your comments.  I do have my application working.  It uses the _layout.cshtml where I have my angular scripts/styles in. The Home/index.cshtml is where I have a <div ng-view> set and is launched using the default MVC HomeController index(). The ng-view will contain my angular application and render their routes and views/partials.  Right now I have the index.Cshtml as my shell.  Work perfectly fine but I'd like my shell to be done using Angular.

Comment: @MikeCheel I believe that when you create a  new project in Visual Studio, you have to select MVC project template first then select Web Api as another template.  Hence the Web Api template is built upon a MVC template.

Comment: In VS2013 you select ASP.NET Web Application and then it takes you to the 'Empty' option . There are three check boxes to chose from (Web Forms, MVC and Web API). If you select the other templates then it does want to make you include mvc.

Comment: @MikeCheel Just tried it and it seemed promising to select the Web api only check box.  Sadly, there are errors when loading the new web api only project.  When you create a new project via your instructions and select the Web Api icon instead of the checkbox it automatically select mvc and web api checkboxes and greys them out.  Thank you for your input though!

Comment: Not from an Empty template. MVC and WebAPI are do not need to be together.

Answer (score 22):

Remove RouteConfig.cs from App_Start, remove the Views directory and all sub-directories including the Views internal web.config file. Comment out or delete all the lines in the Global.asax.cs Application_Start method except GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register). Remove the HomeController, add an index.html and any needed Angular scripts and go at it. I also added solution folders to organize my views as reusing the existing Views folders did not work. I'm using VS 2015 but is should work for 2013 also. PWE

Comment: This seems the correct answer, the Question asked to remove MVC from a Web API project. There are good reasons to answer the question as Paul did here. Like me, @Larbear might be working within a Solution where he has a involved Web API project and he would like to remove the MVC bits only without restarting. Having a step by step list of how to remove just the MVC parts and serve an index.html file instead is very useful with Angular and Aurelia taking over and replacing where we use to plan on using MVC. I've gone from sprinkling SPA fuctionality and going full SPA

Comment: I hade a somewhat different scenario than the OP, wanting to remove MVC from a mainly web forms application (can you imagine! :-)
Other than the steps Paul mention, Don't forget to remove the reference to MVC, that was what finally made my application stop trying to behave in an MVC-ish way.

Comment: confirmed that Culme had suggested the final step which includes multiple packages: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc, Microsoft.AspNet.Razor, Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization, Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages

Answer (score 9):

Web API is not built on top of MVC.

The default templates bring in MVC for the sake of supporting a help page, but you don't need to use it.

You can start with an empty web project and just check Web API.

The routing piece is server routing and it's part of what maps the URL to Controllers+Actions, it has nothing to do with Angular routing.

Answer (score 1):

As Mike Cheel alluded to, there are no dependencies between MVC and Web API. However, if you use the built-in templates, it's easy to get the impression that the 2 are linked. They include a lot of stuff in these templates because they can't anticipate where you want to go with your project... so they try to cover all the bases.

For your purposes, you would probably be better off to start with an empty project and add only the components that you actually need. For this approach, some of the best tutorials and starter projects are from Taiseer Joudeh's "Bit of Technology" blog. His tutorials helped me to build an "MVC Free" web application from scratch that uses JSON Web Tokens and AngularJS Interceptors for security and Web API 2 and Entity Framework to serve up the data.

He has many tutorials on his website... but you might want to start with "[AngularJS Token Authentication using ASP.NET Web API 2, Owin, and Identity](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)". What what.. you didn't ask about security? Well... security is an issue that you will need to confront at some point anyway... and Taiseer presents a nice solution for securing an Angular/Web API application.